# Advanced Custom Fields Deleting Row from repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a repeater with around 270 rows in it, I want to delete a specific row by index using "delete_row()", I can do that easy enough but with 270 rows, this function really seems to hang.  Is this normal behavior? Is there a custom mysql query I can do to delete the row and reindex the existing rows?